# I am creating a Browser App but Android won't detect my app in chooser while I click on any URL

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-intent-chooser

I am creating a Browser app and I want Android to treat my app as a browser and show up in the app chooser to open with. 
[image]

I want my app to show up in this list.

Here is my manifest Activity code:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity.LinkDetectorActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="testscheme" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: What the meaning of browser?

Comment: I am trying to create an app like chrome, or edge

Comment: "I want android to treat my app as a browser" -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: You don't need to internet permission?

Comment: Whenever the user clicks on the link via an app like WhatsApp, Facebook, etc. Android prompts the user to select the browser I want to add my app in the list of all installed browsers.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> Do I need any other permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your intent-filter with below,

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <!-- The BROWSABLE category is required to get links from web 
        pages. -->
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: updated answer. also pls check the url which you are clicking? is it http or https? if https then add that scheme too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change testcheme to "http" and "https"

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity.LinkDetectorActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: sharing 2 links of 2 browser projects, check their manifest, try changes in ur manifest too https://github.com/scoute-dich/browser/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml  
  https://github.com/arunkumar9t2/lynket-browser/blob/master/android-app/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml